# How do I quickly simply verify react.js loaded?

Tags: reactjs

After putting this

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
```

in a blank html file, how do I verify it worked? Is there some command I can issue on the DevTools console that would return eg. true only if the script load was successful.

Comment: Why are you not just checking by using react functions in your project just only for testing purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the existence of `React` in the `window` scope to verify that React has loaded and is present:

```js
// Run this script after <script> block
var isReactLoaded = !!window.React;

console.log(isReactLoaded ? "React Loaded" : "React Not Loaded")
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
```